# PHP User Authentication eDirectory LDAP

Tags: php, ldap, edirectory

I can bind to eDirectory LDAP with PHP.  But I cannot find any, even simple examples about how to build a simple web form, where a user enter a username and password, is authenticated againat their user in eDirectory using ldap or rejected, and then an action is performed.  Does anyone know where I can find some specific exmaples, or can they share please.

Comment: A Google search for "php ldap login form" revealed the following page: http://samjlevy.com/php-login-script-using-ldap-verify-group-membership/

Comment: I am using edirecctory, so that will not work, as the BIND and serach is done differently for AD....

Comment: A Google search for "edirectory php login" revealed the following page: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15651.html